# How to create best json output from mix data structures

Tags: python, json

I am using dicts and lists with this code:

```
def data4circos(assembly_len, reference_len, reference_name, assembly_contigs):

    '''
    [
        {"id":"chr03","label":"chr03","color":"#996600","len":35020413},
        {"id":"tig00007144","label":"tig00007144","color":"#666600","len":40868},
        ...
    }
    '''

    print reference_len
    print reference_len[reference_name]

    print reference_name
    print assembly_len
    print assembly_contigs
    print assembly_contigs[0]
    print assembly_len[assembly_contigs[0]]
```

and it produces the following output:

```
reference_len:  OrderedDict([('chr01', '29070452'), ('chr02', '29511734'), ('chr03', '35020413')])
reference_len[reference_name]: 35020413
reference_name: chr03
assembly_len: OrderedDict([('tig00007144', '40868'), ('tig00000004', '276328'), ('tig00000013', '34218') ])
assembly_contigs: ['tig00007144', 'tig00026480', 'tig00003221', 'tig00010111', 'tig00000318', 'tig00009327']
assembly_contigs[0]:tig00007144
assembly_len[assembly_contigs[0]]: 40868
```

What would be the best way to create json file which looks like this from the above data:

```
[
    {"id":<reference_name>,"label":<reference_name>,"color":"#996600","len":<reference_len[reference_name]>},
    {"id":<assembly_contigs[0]>,"label":<assembly_contigs[0]>,"color":"#666600","len":<assembly_len[assembly_contigs[0]]>},
    ...
]
```

And the final out put should like this:

```
[
    {"id":"chr03","label":"chr03","color":"#996600","len":35020413},
    {"id":"tig00007144","label":"tig00007144","color":"#666600","len":40868},
    ...
]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am unclear on how what you have posted is supposed to match up with your expected output.

Comment: I just update my queston